# How to load sounds gradually in soundPool (Android)?

Tags: android, audio, load, soundpool

I'm doing a soft keyboard with sounds. For each character is some sound. When i clicked to input field it takes a very long time before the keyboard appears ( 3-4 seconds). Because I must load each sound in onCreate() method.
`soundPool.load(context, R.raw.a, 1);
 soundPool.load(context, R.raw.b, 1) etc.;`Is it possible load each sound later? Because if I do not play any sound. I am sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a background thread with low priority? Load the most common keys first in the background thread, and then the less common ones. Your foreground task just loads the images and perhaps a default sound if a key is pressed before the sound for it is loaded..

Then when a key is hit, check to see if the sound is loaded. If not, play the default sound, otherwise play the key's own sound.